# USB ports not working

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive, automount

I installed ubuntu14.04 yesterday through a usb stick. Everything was fine. I installed few softwares and updated everything. Now suddenly usb sticks are not working any more. I inserted pendrives that work in others computer but not mine. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

update:
I connected my phone with data cable its charging.

(ie: I tried other answers but they did not work)

Answer (score 3):

this fixed my problem `sudo modprobe -r floppy`

source: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/fix-usb-devices-automount-not-working.html